# Difference between previous row and next row in pandas gives NaN for first value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to using Pandas and I have a dataframe df as given below

```
    A   B
0   4   5
1   5   8
2   6   11
3   7   13
4   8   15
5   9   30
6   10  477
7   11  3643
8   12  33469
9   13  141409
10  14  335338
11  15  365115
```

I want to get the difference between previous row and next row for B column
I used df.set_index('B').diff() but it gives NaN for first row. How to get 5 there?

```
A   B   
4   NaN
5   3.0
6   3.0
7   2.0
8   2.0
9   15.0
10  447.0
11  3166.0
12  29826.0
13  107940.0
14  193929.0
15  29777.0
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite column b? You are getting `NaN` for the first row as it dont has a previous row.

Comment: I want to preserve first row value and produce difference of others

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
df.B.diff().fillna(df.B)
0          5.0
1          3.0
2          3.0
3          2.0
4          2.0
5         15.0
6        447.0
7       3166.0
8      29826.0
9     107940.0
10    193929.0
11     29777.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: it Produces below result 4,1,1,1,1 in the column which is wrong

Comment: @Himavari check your sample data , and my output , I think your sample data is mismatch with what you have